# Executing git commands from windows batch file, C#

Tags: c#, git, batch-file

I'm trying to write small git client, I just want to use git pull and git clone commands.

I'm doing this:

```
Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "path to my.bat";
            p.Start();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

bat file works fine and executes simple commands but I want to execute git commands from that bat file and git is not recognized.

Is there any right way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/henon/GitSharp

Comment: Thanks @SLaks, I'll try to use GitSharp

Answer (score 0):

put a line in your batch file

```
path
```

and check that the output includes the directory containing the git.exe file.
if not, specify the complete path to the git.exe file.